# How I can know the available memory for each worker?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm using python multiprocessing to do parallel processing. I have a global variable with size 3.4 gigabytes. the Available memory is 64 gigabytes. I arranged 16 workers. How do I know how much memory each worker can be allocated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`psutil`](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) provides information on processes including their memory usage.

Use `psutil.Process(pid).memory_info()` to retrieve usage of each process.

The process id is available in the `pid` attribute of your `multipleprocessing.Process` instance.